# DataMember attribute not found in field properties

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0, attributes

I set to member of class attibute DataMember.

```
[DataMember]
internal protected string _FirstName="";

[DataMember]
public string FirstName { get { return _FirstName; } 
internal protected set { _FirstName=(value!=null?value:""); } }
```

Next I want to search class members which have this attribute. But when I type:

```
Type.GetType("classType").GetProperty("FirstName").Attributes
```

I get null.

Any idea why this attribute was not found by reflection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx), not use the `Attributes` property.

```
var attributes = Type.GetType("ClassType").GetProperty("FirstName")
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true);
```